# Responsibilities taken off me and given to someone else

Tags: resignation, job-description, replacement

I've been at my current job for the last 18 months.

I have a number of different responsibilities there but one of the main ones was a copywriter. I work in-house rather than for an agency.

Recently, a "senior copywriter" (who actually has considerably less experience than me) was hired without anyone telling me until after he'd started. I have now found out that he will be heading up most of the copywriting work from now on. Leaving me with mostly mundane admin / IT work.

I find this a real kick in the teeth seeing as it was one of the main reasons for me taking the job on in the first place. Also the fact that they just hired him right under my nose without saying anything... it's as though they were hoping I just wouldn't even notice.

I've never once been criticised for my performance or even given the opportunity to fix anything. I infact receive nothing but praise for the various responsibilities that I have at the firm.

I'm not sure what to do, I feel like I should talk to my boss about it but feel it is already too late, unless the "senior" copywriter were to suddenly end up quitting then my role as a copywriter there is basically over.

He will do all the creative work and then maybe I'll just be picking up the scraps, e.g. occasionally finishing off what he's done or amending his work into other formats.

I'm also tempted to just look for a new job, but I'd rather at least make it to the 2 year mark first to avoid looking like a job hopper.

There are also a number of other things I like about working here so it would be a shame to just quit, as I'd struggle to find another workplace similar to this one.

Comment: Are you still getting the same amount of money as before, or has something changed in your contract?

Comment: Im still getting the same money yes, Im tempted to just not say anything and use my extra time to just learn some new skills (which is technically part of my job)... and then quit in 6 months or so when things start to get busier

Comment: Was your position described as a copywriter? Companies don’t typically talk to employees when they make hiring decisions unless they will be supervising that individual. How do you know they have less experience than you?

Comment: @Donald it was yes, it was originally one of my main duties. The new copywriter isn't technically my boss but I will be required to get his approval on any work that I produce (and it sounds like there really won't be much of that)

The new copywriter has less than 2 years industry experience whereas I have more around 4 years.

Comment: @user303096 - It sounds like the company wanted a full-time copywriter. It sucks you were not notified of the opportunity. You might want to ask how to apply to internal opportunities like that in the future. Still unclear how you are aware of their experience level if your not going to be their manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's time to have a heart-to-heart with your boss.

But do your homework first. Start with determining what you want from your career and from this conversation. Focus on things that can be done and don't rant. Goals could be: credible a growth path into more creative work with clear metrics and milestones, a different role inside the company, better communication about performance and what happens in the company, etc.

Start perhaps with communication: you thought you were good at copy writing and had no feedback to the contrary. What can be done to learn about performance problems before it's too late to address them?

Then switch to career path: Given that one of your main job responsibilities has been given to someone else, how does you boss think your career path going forward should look like? What does your boss think your strength and weaknesses are and how do those map to what the company needs.

Take your cues from that. If your boss engages in a meaningful discussion, you can see where it goes. If they are evasive and dismissive, than you probably have to make your peace with the situation or look elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will do this. One route that I'm tempted to suggest is for me to go part time. I could then use my spare days to freelance. I'm not sure if it might be too soon to suggest this however with me only having been there for 18 months?

Comment: Part time from a newbie is almost worthless. You need to be spending full time just coming up to speed on the project. Either work with your manager to understand the needs and commit fully to them, or look elsewhere -- but be aware that all jobs are going to involve a heavy learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what to do, I feel like I should talk to my boss about it
> but feel it is already too late

You should talk to your boss and seek understanding for your own career progression.

But if you really feel that it's too late for some reason, find a new job first, then leave this one.